# winforms apps - best way to handle images for performance

Tags: winforms, performance, image

Probably a bad title but I am working on a winforms app and it was all going well until I started doing usability testing at different sizes.

I noticed that the "redraw" of controls on a resize event would go VERY slow. I googled and found that splitcontainers and dockstyle fill don't play well so I changed my approach and the performance improved but it was still slow.

It turns out my background images on my usercontrols was causing the delay and it got me wondering what's best practice for this? I have a few different gradients that are around 1024x768 that are set to sizemode stretch.

My temporary fix is to replace my pretty gradient background with solid black. But that does not make things look as nice. It seems that if I had two different sized background images and swapped them on form_resize that would be most efficient but there is a lot of times where I do things the hard way because I don't know better. So I figured i'd ask here. This is specific to just winforms. I export vector when I can for my wpf/sl stuff.

Comment: Why are your gradients 1024x768? Have you tried making them like 16x16 or something?

Comment: I resized it down to 16x12px and set it as the background image stretched. It still flickers and is very slow to redraw my two datagrids stacked side to side.

Comment: too bad, hoped it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the gradient image very specific? If it's just a linear gradient can't you paint the background yourself?

In the user control, add an OnPaint override like so:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
            Point.Empty,
            new Point(0, this.Height),
            Color.Yellow,
            Color.Green);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(
            brush, e.ClipRectangle);
    }
```

Comment: I will try this and update but I was trying to keep the project with the 2.0 framework (probably should have mentioned that) and i'm pretty sure that lineargradientbrush showed up in 3.5 sp1.

Comment: @TWood It's been in .net since 1.0, so it's safe to use. Good luck!

Comment: Edwin, your example was really helpful. I had to call this as well during object creation to get the best runtime re-paint performance: SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `BackgroundImageLayout` Property to 'None' on your controls with the gradients. This usually gives a moderate performance boost

Comment: so then I would need a massive oversized gradient then? I was using stretch because it allowed me to use the same gradient at all sizes. I just set my gradient at 3300x2800 and backgroundimagelayout to none. It didn't change much unfortunately.